# gcloud, how do I grant appropriate permission to enable sqladmin?

Tags: gcloud

I am doing the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

After authenticating with the command `gcloud auth application-default login`, I run the command to enable sql in the project `gcloud auth applicatoin-default login`, returning the error `ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission`.

How do I fix this? I tried creating a service account with cloudsql permissions but it doesn't work, or I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Could you please specify what role(s) has the user account with which you logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by scouring through other google tutorials, and by reauthenticating and setting the active project with the `gcloud` command. Thanks!